# Borderlands 2 Xbox 1 and Xbox 360 multiplayer?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm gonna get Borderlands the Handsome Collection for Xbox One and give my Xbox 360 copy of Borderlands 2 to my friend. Will we be able to play if he's on Xbox 360 and I'm on Xbox One?

Answer (score 1):

Both of you need to have gold accounts to play online with each other. Giving them the physical disk will allow them the content of the base game. If they want to enter the DLC content with you they will need to buy it on their account.

Comment: Thx bro just wondering if it'll work if he's on 360 and I'm on 1

Comment: Here's a full list of backwards compatible games, BL2 is on the list.
https://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/backward-compatibility/available-games